# Pass params from one application to other by ServerVariable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url, web-applications

I have developed two aplications.
I need that when user presses one button at one of them, he moves by javascript code to the other application.

somthing like:

```
 window.location.href = mySecondAppURL
```

now, I need the second application to get any parmas, but I must implement it by Request.ServerVariable.

The second application is MVC app. So I it look like:

```
 public class myapplicationIndexController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.ServerVariables["MyParam"] != null)
        {
            //my code;
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

How should I pass the params at first application javascript code, for get it at the second application in this way?

---

Update: the first application is Durandal application, what says that there is MVC wrapper but programmer develop in javascript pages.

Comment: What is the application programmed in? Java? You should pass the variables by get method.

Comment: see update in the question body

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `window.location.href = mySecondAppURL?MyParam=aValueHere`

Comment: yes. there are some application that need move user to my second application. My agreement with my customers is that they will send it by ServerVariable. But I don't know how to do it at my first application :(...